# Signing JARs WebStart

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, jide, spring-rcp

I use Java version 1.6.0_19 and created a version of spring-richclient-jideoss-1.1.1_XXXX.

Then a generate a JNLP but when I download the JNLP and I get the error, spring-richclient-jideoss-1.1.1_XXXX is not signer

This error depends the Java version of client, when the JNLP download, it doesn´t happen all Java version.

Could the error be a problem the Java?

Any suggestion???

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I remember there was a bug in the JDK which was solved in update 26. Please update and see if the problem is gone.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/webstart-changes-6u17-until